# Expectation and moments inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

X is a **standard normal random variable**. I came across this inequality in a paper --> $ | E[X^2] | \leq \frac{1}{2} E |X|^3$ ? I am not sure I understand how this works, can someone explain?

Comment: Are there any conditions on $X$? This is not true in general, suppose for instance that $X=1$.

Comment: What if $X=1$ almost surely ? It doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the post. X is a std. normal random variable.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).